# React, can you make an array of elements with Array(n).fill(0).map?

Tags: reactjs

It seems you can not, but I can not nail down why.

Here is my code that is causing the problem :

```
class App extends React.Component {

  render() {

    var elems = Array(~~(this.props.number)).fill(0).map( ()=> <div>test</div>);

    console.log(elems); //(5) [Object,Object,Object,Object,Object]

    return (
      {elems}
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App number='5' />, document.querySelector('#app'))
```

The error points me to  a page in the docs that says 'valid React element (or null) must be returned.'

Im following the example here

```
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html (Basic List Component)
```

thats using an array, so its possible, but somehow mines different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unexpected token when rendering React component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43691502/unexpected-token-when-rendering-react-component)

Comment: Basically, for an inline JSX expression, you have to wrap it in some JSX parent element for it to be interpreted as an inline JSX expression. In actuality you're returning an object `{ elems: elems }` because it's interpreted as `({ elems })` which is an object with shorthand properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Andrew Li pointed out, the original code is returning an non-React Element object which is the source of the error. React expects an object to be returned but the type, `{elems: elems}`, is invalid.

A React component may only (currently) return a single Element (see the caveat in the [React Component docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html#composing-components)) and not an array. Wrapping your array with a parent should do the trick.

```
class App extends React.Component {

  render() {

    var arr = Array(~~(this.props.number)).fill(0).map( ()=> <div>test</div>);

    return (
      <div>
        {elems}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: But it's not actually an array they're returning, it's an object literal...

Comment: It's an array. `map()` is returning an array of objects -- specifically React Elements.

Comment: that's correct, but `return ({ elems })` is interpreted as an object literal with shorthand properties

Comment: That's true. I misread that as JSX delimiting javascript. Hopefully I answered the question the OP intended to ask :/