# Array.fill().map() is not working in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, dictionary, webpack

I tried to use `Array.fill().map()` to make many `div`element in react, its not working.
before making `Array`, it wokrs well. but, now nothing is made.
any answers will be thankful. below is my code.

```js
class Gallery extends PureComponent {
    makeCarouselCell=()=>{
        const cellCount=36
        const degPerCell=360/cellCount
        const className=this.state.deg===degPerCell-10 ? 'choice' : 'carousel_cell'

        return(
            <>
                {Array(cellCount).fill().map((i)=>{
                    <div
                    style={{
                        backgroundImage: `url('./MYBOX/_${i}.jpg')`,
                    }}
                    className={className}>
                    </div>
                })}
            </>
        )
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <>
              <div ref={this.carousel} className='carousel'>
                  <this.makeCarouselCell/>
              </div>
            </>
        )
    }
 }
```

Comment: well makeCarouselCell is a function.... You are using it as a component?

Comment: is that a problem? then why it works before I use Array.fill().map()?

Comment: replace `<this.makeCarouselCell/>` to `makeCarouselCell()`

Comment: replacing doesnt work :(

Comment: The same question
Please see
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44787929/react-can-you-make-an-array-of-elements-with-arrayn-fill0-map

P.S. you just can't do this. You need to create an array in the function, and then put it in JSX

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React, can you make an array of elements with Array(n).fill(0).map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44787929/react-can-you-make-an-array-of-elements-with-arrayn-fill0-map)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of problem here:

1. <this.makeCarouselCell/> to {this.makeCarouselCell()}
2. i is always undefined use index instead

```js
Array(cellCount).fill().map((i ...
```

To

```
Array(cellCount).fill().map(((i,idx) => use Idx
```

3. return statement is missing

```
class Gallery extends PureComponent {
    makeCarouselCell=()=>{
        const cellCount=36
        const degPerCell=360/cellCount
        const className=this.state.deg===degPerCell-10 ? 'choice' : 'carousel_cell'

        return(
            <>
                {Array(cellCount).fill().map((i, idx)=>{
                   return (<div
                    style={{
                        backgroundImage: `url('./MYBOX/_${idx}.jpg')`,
                    }}
                    className={className}>
                    </div>)
                })}
            </>
        )
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <>
              <div ref={this.carousel} className='carousel'>
                  {this.makeCarouselCell()}
              </div>
            </>
        )
    }
 }
```

Comment: is image is not rendering ?, we have to use second index params other i always undefined here, can you try the above snippet it work if you image named sequentially

Comment: You are awesome. it works now, this works <this.makeCarouselCell/>,{this.makeCarouselCell()} both, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide a **key** value

```
  {Array(cellCount).fill().map((item, i)=>{
                            <div
                            key={i}
                            style={{
                                backgroundImage: `url('./MYBOX/_${item}.jpg')`,
                            }}
                            className={className}>
                            </div>
                        })}
```

Comment: I dont think the map is a problem, but thank you for helping me. solve now,

Comment: Please see my update. I didn't mean map is a problem